# Trying to get sum of array values

Tags: php

I got this array and I am trying to make a sum of the `[za]` values but without any success.

My last try was this code:

```
foreach ( $sumza as $sumzakey ) {
              $sum += $sumza[$sumzakey]['za'];
}





Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [za] => 3600
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [za] => 7200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [za] => -27360
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [za] => 3600
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [za] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [za] => 3600
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [za] => 3600
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [za] => 3600
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [za] => 7200
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [za] => 7740
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [za] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [za] => -27360
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [za] => 7200
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [za] => 3600
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [za] => 8640
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [za] => 3600
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [za] => 6840
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [za] => 
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [za] => 5040
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [za] => 5040
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [za] => 5040
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [za] => -27360
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [za] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $sumza as $sumzakey ) {
    $sum += $sumzakey['za'];
}
```

`$sumzakey` actually represents each array within `$sumza`. If you wanted to use your approach you would do:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $sumza as $sumzakey => $sumzavalue ) {
    $sum += $sumza[$sumzakey]['za'];
}
```

In that case you now have the array key for each array element in `$sumza` and can use it to access each array element in `$sumza`. But that would be unecessary and not as clear as the code above.